# Display errors in v-for loop VueJs

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuelidate

I try to display error for each field from a v-for. But I get an error " Cannot read property '$error' of undefined", and I am not sure why.

```
<b-row  v-for="(v,index) in $v.years.$each.$iter" :key="index">
    <b-col>
        <b-form-group>
            <b-form-select
                v-model="v.year.$model"
                :class="{
                    'is-invalid':$v.year.$error, 'is-valid':!$v.year.$invalid}"
            ></b-form-select>
            <div class="invalid-feedback" v-if="!$v.year.required">This field is required!</div>
        </b-form-group>
    </b-col>
</b-row>

validations: {
    years:{
        $each:{
            year:{
                required
            },
        },
    }
},
```

**UPDATE:**

If I remove `year` from :class and v-if, it works, but if I have one error, It shows on each field, instead of just one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is why you shouldn't have such confusing naming scheme. It cannot find `$error` because `$v` property doesn't exist in your loop.

You named the variable `v` not `$v`:

```js
v-for="(v,index) in $v.years.$each.$iter"
```

Comment: @Beusebiu just curious, why do you name your properties so strangely? I've never seen anything like this. Why not just name the list as `years` instead of `$v.years.$each.$iter`? And the symbol `$` in Vue means global, so why use it everywhere?

Comment: I am using Vuelidate, and from what I find there I must use "$v.dates.$each.$iter" insted of just "dates" to work errors for each field in a v-for loop .    https://vuelidate.js.org/#sub-collections-validation

Comment: @Beusebiu Ah, I see, the `vuelidate` team just decided to invent a wheel but made it a square just to be different